# why can't I call my function like main() in python

Tags: function

```
user_input = input("Enter text in Camel case ")
snake_case = convert_snake(user_input)
print(snake_case)

def convert_snake(placeholder):

    snakecase_parts = []
    for character in placeholder:
        if character.isupper():
            snakecase_parts.append("_",charcter.lower())
        else:
            snakecase_parts.append(character)

    snake_case = "".join(snakecase_parts)
    return(snake_case)


convert_snake()
```

why am I not able to summon the convert_snake snake function over here like when you call  after defining it main()

i am trying to write this part of code first

```
user_input = input("Enter text in Camel case ")
snake_case = convert_snake(user_input)
print(snake_case)
```

then create a def function and then call the function  [convert_snake() ]    at the endlike it works in some code but it isn't
working

Answer (score 1):

At the last row you call `convert_snake()` which has no `placeholder` value like the function you have created.

Inside the append("_", ...) you have a variable called `charcter` instead of `character`.

Also:
You cannot append like this: `.append("_",charcter.lower())`

You can use this instead: `snakecase_parts.extend(['_', character.lower()])`

Last but not least you should use the function after you create it and not before:

```py
def convert_snake(placeholder):
    snakecase_parts = []
    for character in placeholder:
        if character.isupper():
            snakecase_parts.extend(['_', character.lower()])
        else:
            snakecase_parts.append(character)

    snake_case = "".join(snakecase_parts)
    return snake_case

user_input = input("Enter text in Camel case ")
snake_case = convert_snake(user_input)
print(snake_case)
```

Comment: Also, `charcter` is a typo (in the original question).